# drawImage лагает при изображении более 400кб

Tags: java, swing, awt

Как я и написал в заголовке, у меня лагает метод Graphics2D#drawImage.

Я создал класс наследующий JPanel, в paintComponent я отрисовал картинку которая весит 400кб и repaint(). Мне нужно было сделать плавную анимацию по Y, но вместо этого начались жуткие лаги. Заменил картинку которая весит не более 50кб и всё пошло идеально.

Находил много разных похожих тем, но они никак мне не помогли

Comment: Укажите в тегах, что вы используете: awt, swing?

Comment: Всмысле awt или swing. Сама отрисовка сделана на awt, а уже рамка ( JFrame ) и остальное это swing

Comment: Ок, указал оба тега. Старайтесь указывать теги к вопросу, так на вопрос с большей вероятностью обратят внимание)